# Cannot load native library on Android: Native library not found in resource path

Tags: android, rust, jna, uniffi

I am developing a Rust library named Galileo with FFI to Android, and am trying to run it in Android emulator.

It compiles fine with the command and produces `x86` directory where you'd expect:

```
cargo ndk -t i686-linux-android -o ./android_ffi build -p galileo
```

I use UniFFI to create Kotlin bindings and it works great:

```
cargo run --bin uniffi-bindgen generate --library target/i686-linux-android/debug/libgalileo.so --language kotlin --out-dir out
```

I then copy generated `x86/libgalileo.so` into my test Android application `jniLibs/x86`, and add generated `galileo.kt` next to `MainActivity.kt`. I also call a function from my `galileo.kt` from main activity.

Then I add dependency to JNA:

```
implementation("net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.14.0")
```

and add the `libjnidispatch.so` to `jniLibs/x86`. After this, the test application compiles successfully, `libjnidispatch` is loaded correctly (I know that, because before I put the compiled library to the correct location, running failed with missing that file). But when run, the application crushes with this in logs:

```
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4134
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'galileo':
dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "android_main" referenced by "/data/app/~~BbeW1CYviVt5gyj4KvK3Mw==/com.example.myapplication-gJRCDqgORFGFroidh0hO1w==/base.apk!/lib/x86/libgalileo.so"...
dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "android_main" referenced by "/data/app/~~BbeW1CYviVt5gyj4KvK3Mw==/com.example.myapplication-gJRCDqgORFGFroidh0hO1w==/base.apk!/lib/x86/libgalileo.so"...
dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "android_main" referenced by "/data/app/~~BbeW1CYviVt5gyj4KvK3Mw==/com.example.myapplication-gJRCDqgORFGFroidh0hO1w==/base.apk!/lib/x86/libgalileo.so"...
Native library (android-x86/libgalileo.so) not found in resource path (.)
```

What I am sure about:

- `libgalileo.so` is compiled with the correct target
- it is put into the correct directory, as `libjinidispatch` is loaded correctly when next to it

What I do not understand:

- Why is there `android_main` in the logs. This `.so` file is not a binary, it's not supposed to be run. There's no `adroid_main` anywhere in my Android or Rust projects.
- Why the library fails to load and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out where this `android_main` comes from, so I post it here in case anyone else struggle with it.

I was following an example to write my rust app, and it used `android-activity` crate. That crate, when added, creates a bridge between Android runtime and rust by exporting functions like `Java_OnLoad`, the ones that Android Native (or Game) activity call when loads the `.so` library. Those methods, created behind the scene, need some way to call into the rust app, so `android-activity` crate uses convention to call `android_main` function, exported by the app. And since my app did not export that function, loading of `.so` failed.

So, to fix this issue, one needs to either remove dependency on `android-activity` crate, or to add the `android_main` method.

Comment: Could you add a code example of how/where you added your `android_main` method? For whatever reason, this solution is not working for me.

Comment: nvm, this answer worked for me. I just needed to delete my build folder.